# Gitlab - Pivotal Tracker integration

Tags: gitlab, pivotaltracker

How do you integrate Gitlab and Pivotal Tracker for free?

I looked at the documentation on pivotal website, and cannot find anything related to that.

Answer (score 8):

Integration to Pivotal Tracker has been present since [Gitlab 6.2](https://about.gitlab.com/2013/10/17/gitlab-ce-6-dot-2-released/). There are more details in a comment on this page:

> You will need to add your user API token under your profile in Pivotal to the Services section on the settings page for a specific project.
>
> Then when you commit you just need to include the story ID in your commit message in the format [#id].
>
> Example Commit:
>
> - Fixed a bug [#123].

Comment: What is and how to get "user API token" ?

Comment: Go to https://www.pivotaltracker.com/profile to get your token, then follow the instructions from Gitlab.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? For some reason I can't find it in GL's documentation.

Answer (score 4):

There’s not much documentation on GitLab. Basically, go to your Project > Settings > Integrations, look for the Project Services header, enable the PivotalTracker integration. You’ll need your token from https://www.pivotaltracker.com/profile; enter that, set it as active, and save changes.

Answer (score -2):

Here are three ways in which you can connect git with Pivotal Tracker:

[ProjectLocker](http://projectlocker.com)

[GitTracker](https://github.com/stevenharman/git_tracker)

[This Script](http://loominate.net/2012/03/24/my-first-greasemonkey-scripts/)